Drama Where Man Has Affair With Dead Son's Girlfriend Named After A Day (Monday\Tuesday\Thursday?)
I think it's a film but it may be TV? May be British, I'm not sure. It's in English, made in the last 10 years.
Plot:
A man finds out about the death of his son (I think a drug related death) and he feels very guilty as he never spent much time with him. He goes to visit the place where his son was living and he meets the girlfriend of the dead son. (Girl possibly involved in drugs also? I can't remember.) Her name is either Monday/Tuesday/Thursday/a day of the week. They are both heartbroken about the death of the son and they are both struggling to cope. They begin an affair, he then moves in.
Later on in the film it's revealed that the girl is actually very young and he didn't know, and also her name isn't actually Mon/tues/thurs/whatever it is. I remember one scene where the girl walks into the kitchen naked to get some food from the fridge and the man says something like 'Thursday you can't go around like that' and then they have sex in the kitchen.
If anyone knows what this is I'd be very grateful, thanks.

Sounds like the UK mini-series Any Human Heart from 2010 based on the novel by the same name about the life of a writer called Logan Mountstuart. In episode 3:

[Logan's] long estranged son Lionel turns up to see him but the boy dies of a drug overdose [...] Logan has to flee New York after an affair with Monday, his son's girlfriend, who has lied about her age and is a minor, rendering him open to prosecution.

Here's the promo:



